# JqGrid record count after search issue

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid v 4.4

I am trying to find the row count in the grid, so below code work and it gives exact record count

```
 var Count = ($("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records'))
```

But after user search something in the grid, it searches and returns the search result, so lets consider the search result consists of 4 rows, so now above code gives me, record =4.

I want to get the record count binded to grid irrespective of search. Please help

Comment: Which `datatype` you use (`"local"`, `"json"`, ...)? In case of usage *server side* filtering jqGrid has no information about the total number of records.

Comment: datatype: "json" but I am also using  loadonce: true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `datatype: "local"` or an remote datatype, but using `loadonce: true` option then the `data` parameter of jqGrid will be array with **all** unfiltered data. Thus you can use the `length` of the array to get the total number of (unfiltered) rows loaded in the grid:

```
var count = $("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data').length;
```